# Visual Studio 2012 refuses to find referenced .dll

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll

I am stuck in DLL Hell. I have a .dll that is referenced in my project. I'll refer to it as project.dll.  Project.dll was created by Visual Studio 2012. I referenced the project.dll by browsing to its bin directory. I can physically see it in the directory.

As soon as I try to debug into project.dll, Visual Studio acts like the thing doesn't exist. It instead gives me a screen that says "Filename.cs" not found." (Did it even look?) Filename.cs is part of project.dll. It gives me the option to browse to filename.cs, which I try to do. I then get an error saying that the source file is different from when the module is was built. This makes no sense, as I just BUILT project.dll and referenced it. I should also add that the error has the following:

Source: Correct Path to Filename.cs

Module: blank

Process: Blank

I have tried all of the following and nothing resolves this:

1. Clean/Build/Rebuild on both projects. (To the point where I want to puke)
2. Clearing browser Cache
3. Deleting temp files
4. Deleting everything under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
5. Verifying that project.dll does not exist in the GAC.
6. Exiting and restarting Visual Studio multiple times.
7. Restarting the computer.
8. Removing the reference, then re-adding the reference.
9. Manually deleting project.dll from the other project's bin folder.
10. Screamed.

How can I get Visual Studio 2012 to recognize that project.dll and filename.cs both exist and are the correct version? Also, perhaps more importantly, how do I prevent this BS from occurring in the future?

EDIT: I just noticed on that "Browse to file" screen, there is textbox says "Original Location" followed by a path that does not exist on my machine. I believe this to be part of the problem. How do I get Visual Studio to stop looking a that invalid path, and instead look at the correct path of where project.dll is referenced from?

Comment: http://superuser.com/ seems a good place to raise this question!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty This looks like a developer question, not IT.

Comment: Is that original location looks familiar to you? I see it doesn't exist now, but is it a location which existed before on your machine? Or is it totally unfamiliar and it was on some other developer's machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this eventually solved it, but I t noticed that the date on MyMainWebService.dll (the project that references project.dll) was outdated. I manually deleted this .dll along with the version of project.dll that was out there. I then built the solution and it found the correct version of project.dll. (It also built the correct date of MyMainWebservice.dll).

What baffles me is why didn't doing a "Clean" remove the outdated version of MyMainWebService.dll?

Answer (score 0):

The "original location" is deducted from the debug information found for the *particular* project.dll instance which was loaded. It is added when that project.dll was built.

What's happening is that your software obviously doesn't load the project.dll what you built, but another one instead. To find out which one, open Visual Studio's "Modules" view: Debug > Windows > Modules. Browse to the project dll in the list and you can find the exact location where it was loaded from. Now you just have to make sure to overwrite that exact project.dll with your copy (or change the way it is loaded so yours will be loaded).

Comment: Hi Csaba Toth.  The path given for the project.dll is located under "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root". I see a file there called "__AssemblyInfo__.ini". Inside that file is the correct path to project.dll.

Comment: How can it be looking for it in the temp folders? I keep deleting from here. To answer your other question from your earlier comment above... the path is from another developer's machine.

Comment: In your case ASP.NET deployment swirls things around a little bit and adds an additional step. Now you have to find another copy of that project.dll (which was compiled by your developer mate). That's where it is deployed from into the temporary folder.

Comment: Deleting anything from that temporary folder won't help, since it is maintained and provisioned by IIS. You have to find where IIS grans that bogus version of the dll (or looking from the other perspective, VS supplies that file to it). Double check the assembly reference to project.dll in your ASP.NET project. You can find what absolute or relative path that project references (that's stored in the csproj file). Maybe that will shed some light.